# Qt Creator: Cannot remote debug from macOS to Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, remote-debugging

I develop an application for Linux on Qt Creator/macOS. I do have a custom script that compiles the code for Linux on a remote build server. I transfer the resulting binary to a Linux test server.

I now start a GDB server like this:

```
gdbserver :1234 my_binary
```

and I want to connect to this server in Qt Creator. I did set up the Linux test machine as remote machine in my kit, the SSH setup works properly. I now click **Debug -> Start Debugging -> Attach to Running Debug Server**, enter `1234` as server port and set **Local Executable** to the local path of the linux executable.

When I try to start the debugger with these settings, I get the following output on a Terminal in Qt Creator:

```
qtc.process_stub: Inferior error:  QProcess::FailedToStart "execve: Exec format error"
```

It seems like Qt Creator tries to run the Linux executable locally (which of course doesn't work). I don't want that; I only want it to connect to the GDB server that's already running. How do I do that?